# Rank in MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table called "MyTable" and it basically lists usernames and points (two columns, name and points). I want to say something like "what is joe1928's rank?", which of course is based off his points. How could I do this in MySQL without having to download all that data and sort it and determine the rank myself?

The person with the highest number of points would be ranked 1.

Comment: What are the criteria/formula to calculate rank ?

Comment: it's based on the points. the person with the highest points is ranked 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting the number of people with a higher score than your user:

```
select count(*) from MyTable where score > (select score from MyTable where user = 'Joe');
```

That will return 0 for the top user.

Answer (score 0):

[This page seems to describe and solve your problem.](http://thinkdiff.net/mysql/how-to-get-rank-using-mysql-query/)

Notes from that page:

```
SET @rownum := 0;
SELECT rank, correct FROM (
                SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, correct, uid
                FROM quiz_user ORDER BY correct DESC
                ) as result WHERE uid=xxxxxxxx
```

Comment: woah this looks complicated. can you show me how I would do it in my table with my specific column names?

Comment: The page I linked describes your problem and solution in great detail.  I suggest trying to read through that.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT @r AS Rank
FROM MyTable u, (SELECT @r := 0)
WHERE (@r := @r + 1) * (u.Username = 'joe1928')
ORDER BY u.Score DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from [TABLENAME] where [USERNAME] = blah order by [POINTS] desc limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the link posted by @Dave your query will look like something below:

```
select Rank,name from
       (select @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS 'Rank', p.name
       from calls p, (select @rownum:=0) r
       order by p.points desc) as rankResults
where name = 'joe';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is from another stack overflow page, seems to solve your problem.

```
    SELECT  uo.*, 
    (
    SELECT  COUNT(*)
    FROM    users ui
    WHERE   (ui.points, ui.id) >= (uo.points, uo.id)
    ) AS rank
    FROM    users uo
    WHERE   id = @id
```